# Can a disconnected surface have a (negative) genus?

Tags: algebraic-topology, convention

This question is rather about a convention.

Is it possible (and conventional) to asign to, say the disconnected sum of two connected surfaces $X=\Sigma_h \sqcup \Sigma_g$ a genus?

Since one has $\chi(X)=\chi(\Sigma_g)+\chi(\Sigma_h)=4-2(g+h)$, is it conventional to set $\chi(X)=:2-2(\mbox{"genus of }X\!\!")$? (in which case one would get for, say $g=h=0$, negative genus $g_X=-1$ for $X=\mathbb S^2\sqcup \mathbb S^2$).

Comment: I don't see any utility to defining genus of a nonconnected surface in this way. It throws away too much information. Generally speaking, a nonconnected surface is understood topologically by simply listing out the numbers of its components of each topological type.

Comment: In topology "genus" really only makes sense for closed connected surfaces. In algebraic geometry there are a few options for a more general definition (arithmetic or geometric genus).

Comment: @LeeMosher Let me disagree slightly by mentioning a utility of this definition. Namely in the context of submanifolds representing elements in $H_2X$. Particularly when trying to find minimal complexity elements (where complexity is only defined in terms of $\chi$), you want to throw away the information of connected components. E.g. for defining the Thurston Norm, there are multiple reasons to get rid of this information.